# Google Drive REST API : file.getCreatedTime() returns always null

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am working with [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android) for Google Drive Rest APi provided at the below link. [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android)

The sample code works fine as is. However when I try to get other details from files like `getCreatedTime()` or `GetWevViewLink()` 'null' is returned. Only getName() and getId() returns values.

Comment: what about getCreatedDate() ? Note I am guessing I don't have the power of android.  file.get returns a file resource you may have to play with it a little https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work. I am using V3 version of the api.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Drive REST APIs v3 would only return only certain default fields. If you need some field, you have to explicitly request it by setting it with `.setFields()` method.

Modify your code like this -

```
private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
    // Get a list of up to 10 files.
    List<String> fileInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileList result = mService.files().list()
         .setPageSize(10)

         // see createdTime added to list of requested fields
         .setFields("nextPageToken, files(createdTime,id,name)")                

         .execute();
    List<File> files = result.getFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            fileInfo.add(String.format("%s (%s)\n",
                    file.getName(), file.getId()));
        }
    }
    return fileInfo;
}
```

You can read more about this behavior here https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration
**Updated link** https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/migration

Quoting from the above link -

> **Notable changes**
>
> - Full resources are no longer returned by default. Use the fields query parameter to request specific fields to be returned. If left unspecified only a subset of commonly used fields are returned.

Accept the answer if it works for you so that others facing this issue might also get benefited.

Comment: Thanks, helped alot, especially since the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the Metadata class to be able to use the [getCreatedDate](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Metadata.html#getCreatedDate()) as indicated in [Working with File and Folder Metadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/metadata).

Then try something like:

```
 ResultCallback<MetadataResult> metadataRetrievedCallback = new
            ResultCallback<MetadataResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(MetadataResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Problem while trying to fetch metadata");
                return;
            }
            //show the date when file was created
            Metadata metadata = result.getMetadata();
            showMessage("File was created on " + metadata.getCreatedDate() );

        }
    }
```